# How to select all product based on category and its parent id

Tags: php, sql

I just want to select all product based on it category id and parent id. I have created 2 table for the above requirement.

1. Category
   Field: id, name, parent_id

   2. product
      Field: id, category_id, category_parent_id, name etc

I created advance search filter for select product based on dropdown category, subcategory, price filter etc.

Please advice me how to search minimum 3 to 4 depth level product searching based on above field and filters.

Comment: Why does your product table have a category_parent_id? The category_id already references all its parents implicitly.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Some DBMS (e.g. MS Access, MySQL) are very limited when it comes to recursion.

Comment: I am using mysql database. My sql query like below.
**********************************************************************


SELECT products.id, products.product_name,products.categories_id,products.parent_id, categories.name FROM products left join categories on products.categories_id = categories.id WHERE categories_id IN ( SELECT id FROM categories WHERE id = 2 UNION SELECT c.id FROM categories c JOIN categories c2 ON c2.id = c.parent_id WHERE c2.id = 15 )

Comment: I want to select all product from category, subcategory and sub sub category. It might be 4 or 5 depth level.

Comment: MySQL doesn't know recursive queries unfortunately. I think one uses stored procedures to solve such tasks in MySQL. Look up how to do recursive queries in MySQL (in StackOverflow or Google) and you will probably find a solution.